# Origine dell’espressione “marcare male”

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-origin

Ho sentito varie volte l’espressione “stasera marca male” con il significato di stasera le cose non vanno per il verso giusto.

In [questo post](https://www.bruttastoria.it/dictionary/marcare-male.html) ho trovato alcuni elementi che, sebbene plausibili, non danno riferimenti riguardo alle fonti:

> Per spiegare questo vocabolo può essere utile riferirsi alla sfera
>   calcistica. Uno dei sinonimi di fare goal è marcare il cartellino. Il
>   nome del **marcatore**, quando segna, è appuntato sul referto arbitrale,
>   così come chi viene ammonito o si fa espellere. Marcare, dunque,
>   significa segnalarsi, contraddistinguersi in positivo o in negativo.
>   In generale **marcare bene** significa dare di sé una buona impressione in
>   una situazione. Ad esempio, nella vita è essenziale marcare bene
>   con la ragazza o il ragazzo, al lavoro, con i professori. Per marcare
>   bene non è necessario stare sopra le righe (quello è fare lo
>   splendido), è sufficiente attenersi alla regole. Al contrario, **marcare
>   male** significa segnalarsi in negativo. Un pessimo **marcaggio** al cinema,
>   ad esempio, è entrare in sala a film già iniziato, far alzare tutta
>   una fila di spettatori per raggiungere il proprio posto e accorgersi
>   dopo che tutti si sono ri-seduti di aver sbagliato film.

Da dove proviene questa espressione? Chi o cosa “marca male”?

Comment: Un’espressione che ho imparato durante il servizio militare, forse legata al *”Marcare visita”*, nel gergo militare, chiedere visita medica, darsi ammalato,per estens. darsi malato per sottrarsi a un obbligo qualsiasi.